# Way to validate a parent/child relation

Tags: hash

I have a rest endpoint for example
`/user/{userId}/message/{messageId}`

I have the possibility to create both ID's as I want.

How can I create `messageId` and know the message is belong to this user,
without checking in database or any service?

I think about hashing `userId` and add the hash as prefix of `messageId`.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is possible without a database lookup, although I also don't understand the motivation.  Presumably this endpoint needs to do *something* with the message that will require a database lookup, so why don't you want to do a lookup?.  It may help if you can explain more of the context.

Comment: Why a hash of the userID? Why not concatenate? I'm not seeing a security angle here as well as not understanding your goal.

Comment: I want to drop fake calls to my service. I don't want to put too much load on my DB. So if I can sanitize the URL before I made a query in the DB, it's better from my side.

Comment: If you want to reduce load, maybe look into a caching solution?

Comment: If you don't want to add load on the DB, use another DB... Redis would be a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, as I understand it, is that you want to ensure that `userID` and `messageID` are an *at least plausible* pair in your front-end before touching the database.

> I think about hashing `userId` and add the hash as prefix of `messageId`.

Assuming you mean URLs like `/user/uuuuu/message/hhhhhmmmmm`, where `uuuuu` is a user-ID, `hhhhh` is a hash of that user-ID, and `mmmmm` is a message-ID, then – even if someone doesn't know what hash algorithm you are using – once they see a valid `uuuuu`/`hhhhh` pair, they can spam you with any `mmmmm` following the hash prefix, and it would look "OK".

What I think you need to do is verify *both* the user- and message-IDs. In addition, to guard against someone discovering which hash algorithm you are using (and thus being able to generate their own verification strings), you want to include a "secret" that is only known to your back-end.

### Creating a URL

1. For a given user-ID `uuuuu` and message-ID `mmmmm` form the string `sssssuuuuummmmm`, where `sssss` is a secret string.
2. Create a hash of `sssssuuuuummmmm` and call it `hhhhh`.
3. The resulting URL is `/user/uuuuu/message/mmmmmhhhhh` (it doesn't really matter which end you stick the combined hash; I've put it on the end because it feels more natural).

### Verifying a URL

1. When your front-end is given `/user/uuuuu/message/mmmmmhhhhh`, form `sssssuuuuummmmm` using the same secret as before.
2. Hash `sssssuuuuummmmm` and compare the result with `hhhhh` from the URL.
3. If they match, then `uuuuu` and `mmmmm` are *probably* a valid pair of IDs and you can check with the database.

Depending on the level of false-positives you want to have to deal with, the `hhhhh` can be an abbreviated form of the hash. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784437/2096401) to the question *How much can you truncate a SHA1 hash and be reasonably sure of having an unique ID?* on StackOverflow suggests at least 45 bits: 64 for safety. An 8-byte *hashlet* would be 16 characters of hex, which should be manageable, although for your situation you could go even shorter, at the risk of an occasional unnecessary database access.